# python extend existing module functionality

Tags: python, pip, python-module, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a private internal module which is kinda big, I want to divide it into small modules, so ill have my main module, and if someone want some more functionality, he will install a module that extend the main module,
(I am using `poetry`, so if its possible with poetry it will be better)

```
pip install mainM
pip install mainM/translators
pip install mainM/secure
etc...
```

I have search around the web, didnt find something really useful

Comment: Maybe "[_namespace packages_](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/)" can help. And also "[_plugins_](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/)" maybe (see [here for plugins in Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#plugins)).

Comment: indeed, the namespace looks like a good solution, thanks!